# Python Beginner: Clerk, smallest number of bills

Tags: python

I need help with the following problem for computer science

A clerk works in a store where the cost of each item is a positive integer number of dollars. So, for example,
something might cost $21, but nothing costs $9.99. 
In order to make change a clerk has an unbounded number
of bills in each of the following denominations: $1, $2, $5, $10, and $20.

Write a procedure that takes two
arguments, the cost of an item and the amount paid, and prints how to make change using the smallest
possible number of bills.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, right now you're literally asking people to do your homework for you.

Comment: this is just your homework, SO is not place to do your homework for you, please ask towards problems with your code.

Comment: For fun (and practice), I implemented this [in Haskell](https://repl.it/NgZt/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am also a beginner, I'll take it as a practice on python. Please see the codes below:

```
def pay_change(paid, cost):
    # set up the change and an empty dictionary for result
    change = paid - cost
    result = {}

    # get the result dictionary values for each bill
    n_twenty = change // 20
    result['$20'] = n_twenty
    rest = change % 20

    n_ten = rest // 10
    result['$10'] = n_ten
    rest = rest % 10

    n_five = rest // 5
    result['$5'] = n_five
    rest = rest % 5

    n_two = rest // 2
    result['$2'] = n_two
    rest = rest % 2

    n_one = rest // 1
    result['$1'] = n_one

    # print(result) if you want to check the result dictionary

    # present the result, do not show if value is 0
    for k, v in result.items():
        if v != 0:
            print('Need', v, 'bills of', k)
```

The logic is to assume the change is over 20, and slowly calculated down, by using `//`, and calculate the rest by using `%`. No matter what, we end up with a dictionary, that gives how many bills are needed for each dollar bill.

And then, for those dollar bills that the value is 0, we don't need to show them, so I wrote a for loop to exam the values in this dictionary.

OK, now I've simplified to codes to avoid repeating snippets, I am quite happy with it:

```
def pay_change(paid, price):
    # set up the change and an empty dictionary for result
    global change
    change = paid - price
    bills = ['$20', '$10', '$5', '$2', '$1']

    # create a function to calculate the change for each bills
    def f(x):
        global change
        result = divmod(change, x)[0]
        change = divmod(change, x)[1]
        return result
    temp = list(map(f, (20, 10, 5, 2, 1)))

    # generate the final result as a dictionary
    result = dict(zip(bills, temp))

    # present the result, do not show if value is 0
    for k, v in result.items():
        if v != 0:
            print('Need', v, 'bills of', k)
```

Comment: you can also use a built-in function here `divmod(x, y)` to get the division and remainder all in once, it could probably save a few lines or make the running slightly faster? But I don't think we need it for such a simple job.

Comment: Now I really used the map and divmod in it, the code could be much simpler and less repeating!